# VHDL - Adding two 8-bit vectors into a 9-bit vector

Tags: overflow, vhdl

This is a pretty simple question, but I haven't been able to make this work yet, nor has any searching on google or here turned up anything really useful.

All I'm trying to do is add two 8-bit vectors and store the result in a 9-bit vector.

```
signal operand1, operand2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);

signal sum : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);

sum <= operand1 + operand2;
```

However I get the warning:

```
Width mismatch. <sum> has a width of 9 bits but assigned expression is 8-bit wide.
```

Shouldn't VHDL have some sort of built in routine to know that an extra bit is necessary for addition overflow?

I have these packages included:

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
```

Perhaps STD_LOGIC_VECTOR is always signed? If so, then I need to define them explicity as unsigned?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If your goal is to do arithmetic on your signals, get into the habit of declaring them with better-suited types for the job: `unsigned` or `integer` are good choices in your case.

Note that to prevent overflow you must concatenate a leading '0' to each operand, instead of doing it to the result:

```
sum <= ('0' & operand1) + ('0' & operand2);
```

Comment: for a general purpose solution that also works with SIGNED types, you can use RESIZE from the numeric_std library (eg sum <= RESIZE(operand1, operand1'LENGTH+1) + RESIZE(operand2, operand2'LENGTH+1) )

Comment: @sbell +1 for the generic solution!

Answer (score 3):

[Use the standard `ieee.numeric_std` library.](http://parallelpoints.com/numbers-in-vhdl/)

Then make your numbers either of `unsigned` or `signed` type, and make use of the handy resize function:

```
answer <= resize(operand1, answer'length) + resize(operand2, answer'length);
```

And bear in mind that many times it's much easier to just use integers, no conversions required, and arithmetic doesn't require you to jump through any resizing hoops!

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion above is correct: use the **unsigned** or **signed** type when implementing arithmetic circuits (remember to include the **numeric_std** package in your code).

Since in your case **sum** has an extra bit (compared to the largest of the operands), the following can be done:

1) If the system is unsigned:

```
sum <= ('0' & operand1) + ('0' & operand2);
```

2) If the system is signed (requires sign extension):

```
sum <= (operand1(N-1) & operand1) + (operand2(N-1) & operand2);
```

Comment: You can also use integers (you don't have to use vector types) and they can simulate faster too.

Comment: Out of interest... are you this Pedroni: http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Circuit_Design_with_VHDL.html?id=b5NEgENaEn4C

Answer (score -6):

Try this: Combine your result with a '0'-vector logically before writing it into the longer vector. For me it worked.

```
sum <= '0' & (operand1 + operand2);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Earlier I tried `sum <= "0" & operand1 + "0" & operand2`, but this did the trick! Thanks.  Still confuses me though about what VHDL would do if the value overflowed into 9 bits but at least the code isn't complaining

Comment: There's a problem with this code: it will overflow and give a wrong result whenever the sum is greater than 255. To prevent overflow, you must concatenate a leading '0' to each operand, instead of doing it to the result: `sum <= ('0' & operand1) + ('0' & operand2);`